# Edit table-cells in a view

Tags: arrays, forms, serialization, yii, html-table

Yii Version 1.1.15

I have a model which contains a serialized array (table) in an attribut. Showing this array as a table in a view works fine.

But I want to update the table-cells and then again save the array serialized in the model. And this does not work. The output stops there (*) without errors.

Here you can see what I did:

$model->table contains a serialized array. The unserialized array looks like this:

```
array(
    array('dog', 'cat', 'cow'),
    array('meat', 'milk', 'gras'),
)
```

I unserialize the table in the controller:

controller: contactController.php

```
$model = Contact::model()->findByPk((int) $id);
$table = unserialize($model->input)

$this->render('contact_form', array(
        'table' => $table));
}
```

And now I want to show and edit the array $table in a form as a html-table:

view: contact_form.php

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'contact-form',
));
?>

<table border="2">
    <?php foreach ($table as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>                
                <td>      
                    <!-- (*) output stops here, without errors -->
                    <?= $form->textArea($value, '', array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20)); ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton("save"); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

The output stops before "... textArea ...".

If I only show $table in a view (without a form) it works like a charme:

```
<table border="2">
    <?php foreach ($table as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
                <td><?= CHtml::encode($value) ?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps to help me :-) How can I get this nice idea working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are missing the arguments of CactiveForm.textArea(.......)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textArea-detail

textArea($value, '', array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20)); ?>

Instead of it your code should be

textArea($model, $value, array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20)); ?>

Comment: $table contains the data not $model. So I tried:
    textArea($table, $value, array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20)); ?>

Comment: $table contains the data not $model  I have tried your suggestion with $table and get an error: "Array to string conversion ". Maybe this is important: As you can see in my code:  $table is not a model, it's just an array.

Comment: public string textArea(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))

as you see first parameter should be a model object
so it would be
textArea($model, $value, array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20));

Comment: I understand that I need a model ... but I only have an array. Is it possible to convert an Array into a Model? And is this possible without a file model/fruits.php? And if it's possible, how?

Comment: Actually you have model on contact_form.php page

$this->render('contact_form', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'table' => $table));
}

this means you have $model at contact_form page

But if you want different Model on that textArea

you can easily do that by  new Fruits()

NB : model/fruits.php (should be Fruits.php )

Comment: I am sorry - having $model too in $this->render ... was confusing. I now deleted it in my example above. And my last post with $fruits was nonsens :-( I meant $table: In the next post I correct it:

Comment: Here corrected: I understand that I need a model ... but I only have an array. Is it possible to convert the Array $table into a Model? And is this possible _WITHOUT_ a file model/table.php? And if it's possible, how?

Comment: I guess it is impossible but you have an alternative solution

Use this

CHtml::textArea($value, '', array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 20));